# How can I link an EPS file into Word for Mac 2011?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, eps

I'm trying to import an EPS file generated in ChemDraw into Word for Mac. I've used the Insert>Picture and Insert>Object options and have chosen to "Link to file".

However, it appears that the EPS is possibly being converted to an image. Essentially, changes to the supposedly-linked EPS file do not reflect in the Word document, even after opening and closing, or trying to Print Preview, or hitting F9.

Is this a fundamental bug/non-function in Word or does anyone have any clues for what I might look into to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to link the EPS file everytime you change it.

Comment: Hmm, do you reckon there's a way to do that with a macro? I noticed in the document.xml that the external file name (not path) is stored in plain text.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never used macros :(

Comment: It appears word 2011 treats eps files differently than png or jpg in that the linked eps file doesn't "link". At least to my experimentation with it...